# XAML MapControl becomes black before loading

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm using the XAML MapControl in Windows Phone 8.1 RT application. I have embedded the map on a page using `<maps:MapControl>`.

My problem is that whenever the page loads, the map control blacks out for a split second before displaying the actual map, thus providing a bad UX. I tried setting the opacity of the control to 0, and reset it to 1 in the `Loaded` event, but even then the map blacks out.

I have to wait for sometime in the `Loaded` event, say by using `await Task.Delay(200)` before resetting the opacity to 1 to solve the issue, but it's a hack.

How do I workaround this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `LoadingStatusChanged`  Event to change the opacity of your map control ..

More: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol.loadingstatuschanged.aspx

Good luck :)

Comment: It's quite surprising to learn that even in the `Loaded` event, the `LoadingStatus` of the map is till `Loading` and not `Loaded`. Any idea why is it like that?

Comment: Its take a time to load whole view of the screen .. at the end, it'll be loaded :) - Loaded Event it's for the UI XAML Element loading status into the view

Comment: Ok, so the `Loaded` event corresponds to the XAML element, and `LoadingStatus` is for the map control itself, is it?